# How to locate select with Selenium, what controlled by javascript?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have the following select.
I want to select specified elements with Java Selenium. I tried these but none of them working, I always got 
In normal usage If I click on the element its

> no such element: Unable to locate element:...

Heres the my code(s):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value=\"2498847\"]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/div/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/font/select/option[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/form/div/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/font/select/option[2]")).click();
```

Tired with Select class:

```
Select selector = new Select(this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select")));
selector.selectByVisibleText("Harris_SF_1");
```

What am I doing wrong?
Or Is it possible to simulate a javascript click and call this script with Selenium?

Html:

```
<select size="10" name="DropDown" onchange="fSaveSearch(document.Form1.DropDown);">
    <option value="1715424">1960 cypress creek N</option><!---this shows the saved searches list--->
    <option value="2164877">Broker Closing Search</option>
    <option value="2498847">Harris_SF_1</option>
    <option value="1715426">Spring East</option>
    <option value="1715428">Spring Klein</option>
    <option value="1715429">Spring Klein Tomball</option>
    <option value="1715427">Spring NE</option>
    <option value="1715432">The Woodlands</option>
</select>
```

The final goal, to simulate a click on a option with specific visible text or value.

Edit: The site default iFrame is not that where these elements/js writter. If I change the iframe at the chrome console it works, but

```
driver.switchTo().frame("SearchFrame");
```

Doenst work am I change wrong?

[image]

Comment: Wht does the javascript onchange function do? Have you tried locating the select by name attribute?

Comment: When you bring the page up under google chrome, right click the target element, and under dev tools, right-click the high-lighted html, select Copy -> Copy XPath, what does the XPath string look like?

Comment: /html/body/form/div/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/font/select/option[3]  this is the chrome suggested xpath.

Comment: So the element is located under frame right..So is the switchToFrame method throw any exception? And why dont you go by `name` selector.. `findElementByName('DropDown')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Madhan  your comment solved the my problem.
But it only worked after I swtich to Defaultcontent, then I switch to the frame I need!

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

then switch to the frame I needed:

```
driver.switchTo.frame("Frame_ID");
```